# Compile and Link C++ with Fortran

Tags: c++, linker, g++, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a valid Fortran 77 file using the `gfortran` compiler. I use the following command to compile the Fortran:

```
gfortran -c main.f -o main-fortran.o -llapack -lblas
```

I also need to link this with a C++ program, which is compiled, like so:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main-cpp.o
```

Both of these files compile without any errors or warnings.

However, I cannot link them together into an executable. Here is the command I am using:

```
g++ main-cpp.o main-fortran.o -o run.exe -lgfortran -llapack -lblas
```

The linker then gives this error:

```
main-fortran.o: In function `main':
main.f:(.text+0x2e18): multiple definition of `main'
main-cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8e9): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You can find the source files here: [C++](https://github.com/ffiadmin/independent-study/blob/master/main.cpp) and [Fortran 77](https://github.com/ffiadmin/independent-study/blob/master/main.f).

Any idea what I can do to overcome this?

Comment: A program **must** have only one main(), if more than one then which one should be called by OS when program starts?. You declared a main() both in Fortran and C modules. Delete one of them.

Comment: @Adriano I don't have the word "main" in the Fortran source code: https://github.com/ffiadmin/independent-study/blob/master/main.f Is the compiler adding it in implicitly?

Comment: it's not a word, it's a function name (in C). In C it's application's entry point (and you have in your fortran program). let's replace _main_ with _entry point_. Linker says: you have two entry points for your application, one in main.f and one in main.c then I don't know which one should be used (called by OS to run the linked program).

Comment: @spryno724 try to remove the "initialization" section with the bare "end". Seems that's detected as main program body.

Comment: @Netch Removing the "end" statement causes the compiler to give several errors, like this: `main.f:55.6: subroutine setNBasis(value) Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)`

Comment: @spryno724 well, sorry, my Fortran knowledge has finished with early F77 versions. AFAIR common sections and parameters shall be provided to each compiled subroutine/function separately. If so, you should remove the whole code up to this "end" and keep only explicitly declared functions and subroutines (since line 39). This code isn't proper for a library; you'd put it into another file which uses the library.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main programs: one in C++ and one in Fortran.  Delete the Fortran one either by

Option 1:
The first bit of your Fortran program should be a BLOCK DATA segment.  Just add

```
BLOCK DATA INFO
```

At the start.

Option 2:
Delete everything up to the first END.